# How to translate the content in a paragraph into any Indian local language using javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, office-365, multilingual

I am building a multilingual SharePoint app especially for Indian Farmers, using Office 365. How do I achieve to translate the given paragraph text to convert it to any Indian local language selected in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find a translation service that you can access via REST such as [Google's](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest) or [Bing's](https://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) translation APIs if they support your languages. The problem is you really should write a proxy service and host it so that it can be accessed via your app. This will prevent someone from using your API developer key. You could use SharePoint 2013's proxy if this were on prem.

At that point your App would just need to post the text that you have selected in your App to the translation service of your choice via the proxy. This will take time, so there has to be some sort of way to check that the translation job has completed.

You should also be aware that there are other ways to integrate machine translation into SharePoint. See this article from MSDN: [Machine Translation Services in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163145%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Since google's API is paid, I have used BING's API, and it is working but that API is for the languages of particular countries. Can I  get BING's API or any other API for Indian languages such as Tamil, Telugu, Punjabi, Gujarathi, Marathi.

Comment: That's not really a SharePoint related question ad since it's kind of specialized I'd suspect you will need to use a paid service.